# Why does the object remain null after trying to assign here in this code snippet?

Tags: java, file

Here the task is reading from a file some lines and creating objects of type "Plant" and adding them into the ArrayList "plants" which is a field in the class Plant. I am supposed to make the reference tempPlant refer to a specific child instance of Class "Plant".

Every time I read from a file and try to create an instance of class Plant it fails.

I tried using a buffered reader as well but it didn't workout as well and seemed like the code would get a bit more verbose (which is a usual situation in Java that I am trying to avoid). Please help.

Update: the file is expected to have only lowercase entries for the "type". Whenever I run it reads them from the file but it doesn't perform this check `if ('p'== type)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Planet zelda = new Planet();
    File myFile = new File("in1.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);

    int numOfLines = sc.nextInt();
    int days;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++) {
        String name = sc.next();
        String typeStr = sc.next();
        char type = typeStr.charAt(0);
        int nutrients = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(type);
        System.out.println(nutrients);


        Plant tempPlant = null;
        if ('p'== type) {
            tempPlant = new Puffs(name, nutrients);
        } else if ('b'== type) {
            tempPlant = new Parabush(name, nutrients);
        } else if ('d' == type) {
            tempPlant = new Deltatree(name, nutrients);
        }
        zelda.addPlant(tempPlant);

    }
    days = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();

    zelda.start(days);

}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include what you expect to happen and what happens instead? Any error message?

Comment: Are you sure the `type` value is reading correctly? Is it wise to assume you'll only see p, b, and d?

Comment: does your file contain `'p'`, `'b'` and `'d'` also in **lower case**?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle yes, we expect the type to be only lowercase for now. Any clue what could help ?

Comment: @shawnt00 we expect the types to be only lowercase, I also tried using .equals() but it didn't help.

Comment: When you debug your code what does `typeStr` contain? Maybe it would be easier to help you if you can provide a snippet of `in1.txt` file so that we can test this on our own.